# Why style for <select> not working in same way in all browser?

Tags: jquery, css, xhtml, cross-browser

This is HTML

```
<div class="DatetimePanel">
    <select class="DaysList">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>
        <option value="7">7</option>
        <option value="8">8</option>
        <option value="9" selected="selected">9</option>
        <option value="10">10</option>
        <option value="11">11</option>
        <option value="12">12</option>
        <option value="13">13</option>
        <option value="14">14</option>
        <option value="15">15</option>
        <option value="16">16</option>
        <option value="17">17</option>
        <option value="18">18</option>
        <option value="19">19</option>
        <option value="20">20</option>
        <option value="21">21</option>
        <option value="22">22</option>
        <option value="23">23</option>
        <option value="24">24</option>
        <option value="25">25</option>
        <option value="26">26</option>
        <option value="27">27</option>
        <option value="28">28</option>
        <option value="29">29</option>
        <option value="30">30</option>
        <option value="31">31</option>
    </select>
    <select class="MonthsList">
        <option value="1">January</option>
        <option value="2">February</option>
        <option value="3">March</option>
        <option value="4">April</option>
        <option value="5">May</option>
        <option value="6">June</option>
        <option value="7" selected="selected">July</option>
        <option value="8">August</option>
        <option value="9">September</option>
        <option value="10">October</option>
        <option value="11">November</option>
        <option value="12">December</option>
    </select>
    <select class="YearsList">
        <option value="1998">1998</option>
        <option value="1999">1999</option>
        <option value="2000">2000</option>
        <option value="2001">2001</option>
        <option value="2002">2002</option>
        <option value="2003">2003</option>
        <option value="2004">2004</option>
        <option value="2005">2005</option>
        <option value="2006">2006</option>
        <option value="2007">2007</option>
        <option value="2008">2008</option>
        <option value="2009">2009</option>
        <option value="2010" selected="selected">2010</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

This is CSS

```
select {
background:#F3F3F3;
border:1px solid #BFC2CC;
color:#555555;
padding:3px;
}
```

This is output

In **IE7** and **IE8**

[alt text http://shup.com/Shup/380925/11061093625-My-Desktop.png](http://shup.com/Shup/380925/11061093625-My-Desktop.png)

In **FF 3.5**

[alt text http://shup.com/Shup/380926/11061093718-My-Desktop.png](http://shup.com/Shup/380926/11061093718-My-Desktop.png)

In **Google Chrome**

[alt text http://shup.com/Shup/380927/11061093822-My-Desktop.png](http://shup.com/Shup/380927/11061093822-My-Desktop.png)

It's only working accurately in Firefox. how to get same in IE and Chrome?

is there any jquery solution?

I just want to apply my css in all browser, same way. don't need fancy customization for `select`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Input elements, especially `select` s and file inputs, are notoriously difficult to style. Some browsers use the operating system's user interface to render controls; others don't allow access to all the properties (e.g. styling a file upload's "select" button).

If you want 100% streamlined design, you should use a custom, JavaScript-based select element. There are many good solutions in the jQuery camp, many of which degrade gracefully if JavaScript is not present.

Comment: Hi pekka i just need the style which is applying on Firefox in my screenshot, want to apply in same way in all browser. can you what is the lightest solution to do this with help of javascript? i dont' want any facny thing just need same css style in all browser.

Comment: @Jitendra that's not as easy as it looks, because all the Javascript things are complete rewrites of the select functionality. This one looks good for exmaple: http://www.prismstudio.co.uk/2009/05/jquery-plugin-stylish-select-unobstrusive-select-box-replacement/ haven't used it myself yet, though.

Comment: this is slightly overkill. I just want to apply my css in all browser same way. don't need fancy customization for `select`.

Will look for any jquery solution.

Comment: @metal I agree. But there is no way to simply apply CSS to those normal UI elements, with or without jQuery. You would need a totally re-written component like the one I linked to.

Comment: You only need JavaScript for an onclick even, the rest can be done with ordinary HTML & CSS.  (Not that drop-in JS libs for this aren't convenient.)

Answer (score 1):

> I just want to apply my css in all browser, same way. don't need fancy customization for select

Fancy customisation's are generally a way of making up for lack of browser support for basic things like this. If you want a pure CSS solution, your only option is to report this as a bug in Chrome and IE and wait. It's simply something only Firefox and Opera currently support.

Webkit does provide you with some proprietary stuff, which is fairly hackish, but will give your slightly more freedom:
`select{ -webkit-appearance:none; }`
though that's not really recommended as might be unintuitive for Webkit users.